# Objects are not valid as a React child - found: object with keys

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I try to setState but it does not accept the JSON responses I fetch from a URL. but the response looks ok, it is an array of objects:

```
{"songs": 
  [
     {"id":1,"name":"Hello","singer":"Adele","img":"adele.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Adele.mp3"}, 
     {"id":2,"name":"de una vez","singer":"Selena gomez","img":"selena.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Selena.mp3"}, 
     {"id":3,"name":"Bayda","singer":"Navid","img":"navid.png","type":"pop","mp3":"Navid.mp3"}, 
     {"id":4,"name":"Takin' Back My Love ","singer":"Enrique Iglesias","img":"enrique.png","type":"Pop","mp3":"Enrique.mp3"}
  ]
}
```

**and here is my react component:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8765`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonRes => {
      
      // setPlaying(jsonRes[0]);
      setSongs(jsonRes.songs);
      // jsonRes.songs.map(song => setSongs([...song]))
      console.log('Songs are: ', jsonRes.songs);
    });
    
  }, []);
  // console.log('songs:', songs)
  // console.log('playing:', playing)
  return (
    <div>
      Hello from App Songs: {songs}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `map` to display an array in React.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I totally forget about that {songs} object inside return. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This songs array is an array of objects and you cannont pass it to the return statement. If you want to have the content of if you need to do as below in your return statement, for example you want to show the name of each song:

```
{songs.map(song => {
        return (
          <div>{song.name}</div>
        )
      })}
```